# Add tooltips to the questions on the profile page

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, profile-page, tooltips

***I have migrated this request from now deleted "[New User Profile - LIVE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live)" thread where it received ~25 upvotes.***

It would be convenient to have tooltips in the ["Summary"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158912/idolon?tab=summary) section. For example, on the old profile page we could see number of views and answers right near the question. Since this information is not available anymore on the summary tab (you have to open ["Questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158912/idolon?tab=questions) tab to see it), mentioned numbers can be shown in the question tooltip instead:

Proposed:

[image: Proposed profile change - With hand-drawn red circle]

Old:

[image: Old profile page]

---

Comment: I am all for having _more_ information available, especially in an unobtrusive way like tooltips. Having interesting tidbits of info in tooltips on just about everything is one of my most favorite-est things in the whole wide world. Well, after ponies...and perhaps hand-drawn red circles...this post needs more circles.

Comment: @cdeszaq Yep, it looks better now :)

Comment: +1, though I'd prefer [the tags of the question included](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120653/add-tags-to-profile-page-links-to-questions-and-answers)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - I think the view / vote / answer count could be a tooltip on the vote number, and the tags could be a tooltip on the question title. Keeps things a bit cleaner. Good idea though.