# New Summary page doesn't show answers given

Tags: discussion

Initially when I used to click on the username then I used to get to the summary page. There I could see how many of my questions received answers. But now they only show votes and not the answers given.

I have to click to individual questions to see if an answer is given or not.

Is it possible to change the votes to answers? Answers are more important than votes there. Or maybe show both like before.

Comment: You may also vote for my feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118607/158912. It requests tooltips (with number of answers given) for the questions on the Summary tab.

Answer (score 1):

View the [Questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155683/user1155683?tab=questions) instead of the summary, it show the list exactly like in the old design.

You might try and suggest feature request to remember the last tab you viewed then when clicking on user name you'll see this always (until explicitly clicking the summary tab again) but I doubt the community will  welcome this.

Comment: That is ok but no point of votes showing in summary tab

Comment: Why not? In Stack Overflow the votes count is the most crucial piece of  data about posts. It "measure" how good (or bad) the post is.