# Add tags to profile page links to questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, profile-page, tooltips

It is great to see selection questions/answers directly on the new profile page, but since it is a compressed overview, it lacks the otherwise present information on tags that post has. So adding these to the (currently unused) tooltip would be great.

Comment: I agree that the tooltip would be a good place for this info.